# Draw Arcs On Spherical Caps With Fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d, tikz-calc

I asked this question:
[Draw Arcs On Spherical Caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591354/draw-arcs-on-spherical-caps/591364#591364) 
and a user was kind to answer.

However, I am trying to improve on design by changing some colors, adding fill, and adding coordinate (x,y,z) axis with these properties [dashed, line width = 0.1pt, black], etc.

Here is how I envision it (fill not drawn but needed in LaTeX):

[image]

I need a bit of help with adding the fill and coordinate axis, vectors etc.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass[letter, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}

\usepackage{float}

% For Conical Resistor Figure
    \def\ch{3.75} % cone height
    \def\cv{2}    % cone visibility height
    \def\ph{20}   % cone angle
    
    % isometric axes
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cr {\ch*tan(\ph)} % cone radius
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cg {\ch/cos(\ph)} % cone generatrix
    \pgfmathsetmacro\crv{\cv*tan(\ph)} % cone radius     (not visible part)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cgv{\cv/cos(\ph)} % cone generatrix (not visible part)
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro\gs{sqrt((2*\ch*\ch-\cr*\cr)/(3*\cr*\cr))} % generatrix slope
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xt{sqrt(6)*\gs*\ch/(1+3*\gs*\gs)}         % tangent point x
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yt{\gs*\xt}                               % tangent point y
    \pgfmathsetmacro\aa{(\ch*\zz-\yt)/\xy/2-\xt/\xx/2}         % coordinate x in xy plane
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{(\ch*\zz-\yt)/\xy/2+\xt/\xx/2}         % coordinate y in xy plane
    \pgfmathsetmacro\at{atan(\bb/\aa)+180}                     % angle to the tangent point
%




\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}]
            \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\ch]
                \draw[magenta] (0,0) circle (\cr);
                \fill[magenta!40, opacity=0.9] (0,0) circle (\cr); % fill of big cap
                \fill[magenta!40, opacity=0.9] (1.75,1.75) circle (\crv); % fill of small cap
            \end{scope}
            % meridians
            \foreach \a in {0,30,...,179}
            {%
                \begin{scope}[rotate around z=\a, canvas is xz plane at y=0]
                    \draw[line width=0.1pt, magenta] (0,0) ++ (90-\ph:\cg)  arc (90-\ph:90+\ph:\cg);
                    \draw[line width=0.1pt, magenta] (0,0) ++ (90-\ph:\cgv) arc (90-\ph:90+\ph:\cgv);
                \end{scope}
            }
            % parallels
            \foreach \i in {1,2} \foreach \j in {\cg}
            {%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\a{\i*\ph/3}
                \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={\j*cos(\a)}]
                    \draw[line width=0.1pt, magenta] (0,0) circle ({\j*sin(\a)} );
                \end{scope}
            }
            \foreach \i in {1,2} \foreach \j in {\cgv}
            {%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\a{\i*\ph/3}
                \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={\j*cos(\a)}]
                    \draw[line width=0.1pt, magenta] (0,0) circle ({\j*sin(\a)} );
                \end{scope}
            }
            % body
            \draw[dashed, magenta] ($(\at:\crv)+(0,0,\cv)$) arc (\at:450-\at:\crv);
            \draw[dashed, black] (0,0,0) -- ($(\at:\crv)+(0,0,\cv)$);
            \draw[dashed, black] (0,0,0) -- ($(90-\at:\crv)+(0,0,\cv)$);
            \draw[magenta] ($(\at:\cr)+(0,0,\ch)$) -- ($(\at:\crv)+(0,0,\cv)$) arc (\at:90-\at:\crv) -- ($(90-\at:\cr)+(0,0,\ch)$);
            % a bad attempt at adding fill
            \fill[magenta!40, opacity=0.9] ($(\at:\crv)+(0,0,\cv)$) arc (\at:90-\at:\crv) -- ($(90-\at:\cr)+(0,0,\ch)$) arc (\at:450-\at:-\cr) -- ($(\at:\crv)+(0,0,\cv)$);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
    
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Since I do not understand the code quite well, I would truly appreciate the help.

**Also, it would be amazing if someone can help me offset the point in the center of the ellipse to be more north (middle of the semi-minor axis)? I think it will look more realistic. That is what I tried to do in my hand drawing.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A Minimal Working Example (MWE) must be provided only with necessary packages.  You need to remove the unnecessary ones.

Comment: I removed unnecessary packages. It is updated now.

Answer (score 4):

This draws a spherical cap with half circles at various angles. Unfortunately I could not use your MWE since all sorts of things are hard coded, so it is very cumbersome to compute the critical angles that determine where solid lines need to turn dashed. On the other hand, with `tikz-3dplots`, which is used here, this is a neat little exercise in trigonometry since the view angles are known. Due to the rotational symmetry and the fact that the z-axis is "up", there is only one relevant view angle, the latitude angle theta, which you can adjust to your needs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{90}% keep 90 fixed but feel free to change the first argument
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,line join=round,
    declare function={R=2;
    tcrit(\x)=180-atan2(sin(\tdplotmaintheta),cos(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\x));}]
 \foreach \Angle in {-75,-45,...,75}    
  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tcrit}{tcrit(\Angle)}
  \draw[dashed] plot[variable=\t,domain=\tcrit:180,smooth] 
   ({R*cos(\Angle)*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\Angle)*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)}) ;
  }
 \draw[dashed] (0,-R) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-270,radius=R];
 \begin{scope} 
  \clip (0,-R) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=90,radius=R]
   [tdplot_screen_coords] --(R,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=R];
  \shade[ball color=magenta,fill opacity=0.6,tdplot_screen_coords] 
    circle[radius=R];
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \Angle in {-75,-45,...,75}    
  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tcrit}{tcrit(\Angle)}
  \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:\tcrit,smooth] 
   ({R*cos(\Angle)*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\Angle)*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)}) ;
  }
 \draw (0,-R) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=90,radius=R]
  [tdplot_screen_coords] -- (R,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=R]
  -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution!! However, I do not need the top half of a sphere. That is too much. Could you tell me how to get only the top 25% of the sphere? The rest can stay the same (design).